Number of ways to "map" elements from initial set to multiple destination sets
The question is about a first set in which I have a number of elements and $m$ sets in which I want to put them in all possibile ways despite ordering. For example I can say that first set $P=\{1,2\}$ and $m$ sets are $A$ and $B$ which are "destination" sets. One way could be $A=\{1,2\}$ and $B=\{\}$, an other way $A=\{1\}$, $B=\{2\}$, etc. I looked for it but I couldn't find anything about something like that. Maybe it's because I'm not a mathematician specialized in combinatorics and I've not instruments in order to solve this problem.
Any help, answer or clarification is very appreciated.
Thanks

It sounds like you are simply asking how to count the number of functions from $P$ to $\{A, B\}$. In general, the cardinality of the function set $X \to Y$ is $|Y|^{|X|}$ when both $X$ and $Y$ are finite sets. I'm sure there are many answers on this site that explain this in detail. In your case $|P|^m = 2^2 = 4$.

Thank you very much, my lackness of mathematical words didn't let me find this elementary answer.
